# Vector potential, magnetic field and dipole moment due to a rotating cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, vector-fields

I've been struggling with the following problem:

Consider a cylinder with height h and radius a with a homogeneous surface charge density $\sigma$ rotating about its symmetry axis with constant angular velocity $\omega$.

Determine:

a) The potential vector ($\vec{A}$) over all the space

b) The magnetic field ($\vec{B}$) over all the space

c) The magnetic dipole moment

So far I have developed the following.

I decided to work with cylindrical coordinates and cylindrical vector base such that

$\vec{r}\ =\ \rho \hat{\rho}\ +\ \phi \hat{\phi}\ +\ z\hat{k}$

Then the angular velocity is $\vec{\omega}\ =\ \omega\hat{k}$

With that in mind I built the current density vector as:

$\vec{J}\ =\ \sigma\omega a\delta(\rho' - a)\hat{\phi}\ +\ z\hat{k}$

Where $\delta$ is the usual Dirac delta and considering that the location of the current is $\vec{r}'\ =\ (a,\phi',z')$ for the surface of the cylinder wihtout the top and bottom cap

I'm not sure if that way of building $\vec{J}$ is correct because when I try to integrate over it to get the vector potential $\vec{A}$ I end up with:

$$\vec{A}\ =\ \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\ \int d^3r'\ \vec{J}G(\vec{r};\vec{r}')$$

with $G(\vec{r};\vec{r}')\ =\ \frac{1}{||\ \vec{r}\ -\ \vec{r}'  \ ||}$ the Green function.

I would appreciate any comment or hint that can lead me to get the answers

Comment: I'm trying now with $\vec{J}\ =\ \sigma\omega a \delta(\rho '\ -\ a)\ \hat{\phi}$

Comment: The Green function $G(\vec{r};\vec{r}')\ =\ \frac{1}{||\ \vec{r}\ -\ \vec{r}'  \ ||}$ is only valid for spherically symmetric problems. You need a Green's function with cylindrical symmetry.